# Clistctrl item search focus

Tags: search, focus, selectionchanged, clistctrl

I'm having some trouble while trying to create a "Search" function in a ClistCtrl.
When the searched item is found I know for sure it is marked as the correct data is displayed, yet the list itself doesn't show the item. I want the list to move its focus on the new item that was searched and show it but for some reason can't find the way to do so.
I'll just add that the "Always Show Selection" option is turned on in the Dialog options.

Appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to highlight the new item?

Comment: No, not highlight. I'll use an example; lets say for instance the list is 100 items long but due to the window's size only 10 item are show (therefore you have a scroll bar). If I see items 1-10, and search for item 50, for instance, I want the list show me the item I searched for and that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Update,
I've found the function that solves the issue - EnsureVisible. Make sure that the second argument you insert, bPartialOK, will false in order to get full visibility of the the list item.